# DateTime not working in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I've got this line of code

`<h3> <script>Date.now</script>{{$flow.files[0].name}} </h3>`

Basically All i'm wanting to do is put the date infront of the filename thats generated from the {{}}.

It currently shows nothing, The unix timestamp might be better but i can only get it to show text that i type infront.

I have tried `{{Date.now(); $flow.files[0].name}}` Which hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with JavaScript like your first attempt, you should have something like this:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <span id="dateHere"></span> - {{fileName}}
    <script>
    document.getElementById("dateHere").innerHTML = Date();
    </script>
</div>
```

and if you want to have more control on your date format:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='Ctrl'>
        <span id="dateHere"></span> - {{fileName}}
        <script>
        document.getElementById("dateHere").innerHTML = Date();
        var date = new Date();
        var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
        var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
        var currentDate = date.getDate();
        var customDate = currentMonth + '-' + currentDate + '-' + currentYear;
        document.getElementById("dateHere").innerHTML = customDate;
        </script>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.fileName = 'your file name';
  })
</script>
```

-> [on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7i7157jP84iOHYMOqNjv?p=preview)

Comment: This didnt do anything except break everything, Quickly remove this

Comment: @ddsbro lol well you are supposed to edit it! of course it'll break your code if you just copy and paste it somewhere :)

Comment: @ddsbro ignore the `ng-app` and `{{fileName}}`, just use the rest of the code to get the time you want and then add the rest of your angular stuff to it

Comment: Ha yes i did that , This is what i ended up with, `<script>
document.getElementById("dateHere").innerHTML = Date();
</script>
                <h3><span id="datehere"></span>{{$flow.files[0].name}} </h3>`

Comment: @ddsbro good. I've added an example to my answer. you might want to check that out also

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Controller:

```
$scope.myDate = new Date();
```

HTML:

```
{{myDate | date: 'MMM d, y h:mm:ss a' }} {{$flow.files[0].name}}
```

I used the [filter date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to format the date.